# What is the mathematical definition of f(n) and O(f(n))

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o

Can someone please give the mathematical definition of `f(n)` and `O(f(n))`?

Comment: One is "function of n" and the other is "Of the order of a function n".

Comment: Wrong place to ask is the 1st answer.

Comment: [Plain English explanation of Big O](http://stackoverflow.com/q/487258/3789665)

Answer (score 1):

You can check this page to see a [math definition of big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

---

Let `f` and `g` be two functions defined on some subset of the real numbers. One writes

[image]

if and only if there is a positive constant `M` such that for all sufficiently large values of `x`, the absolute value of `f(x)` is at most `M` multiplied by the absolute value of `g(x)`. That is, `f(x) = O(g(x))` if and only if there exists a positive real number `M` and a real number `x0` such that

[image]

In many contexts, the assumption that we are interested in the growth rate as the variable x goes to infinity is left unstated, and one writes more simply that `f(x) = O(g(x))`.